# Oracle big excel import

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rds

I have Oracle AWS RDS. I want to import big excel files of size 600 MBs. How can I do it?

I tried using Oracle SQL developer but it hangs.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why isn't it working? Can you import small files? A little effort, please.

Comment: Yes, small imports is working very well. I'm breaking the file into 10K records  and it works well. But how can I import all of it at once. I have around 320K rows in every file.

Comment: Can you save as CSV and use sqlloader or an external table?

Comment: Oracle SQL developer is not suitable for importing such huge files. You can either use SqL Loader or external tables as suggested by @OldProgrammer or split the file into smaller parts and load it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import data into an Oracle based RDS.
One way to do it, is to create an Oracle data dump file. ( Installing an Oracle DB to your local machine, import your data locally, then create the dump file.)

This scenario was working for me.
See tutorial for this and other methods in the relevant AWS source:
[Data import to Oracle RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)